# Bootsy - some buttons not displaying properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootsy for the first time. The setup seemed okay, I just followed the instructions in the [rdoc](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy). For the most part the editor is fine but some of the buttons are not displaying correctly. I've uploaded a screenshot of how they appear [here](http://s3.postimg.org/u2wdv46hf/Untitled_1.png).

In my form partial I have:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.bootsy_area :description, :class => 'form-control', rows: 12 %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in config/initializers/bootsy.rb I have

```
 config.editor_options = {
   font_styles: true,
   emphasis: true,
   lists: true,
   html: false,
   link: true,
   image: true,
   color: true
  }
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: have you added Bootstrap 3 properly to your application with the javascripts?